# priority queue in opencl

Tags: opencl, a-star

I am trying to implement the A-Star search algorithm on OpenCL an can't figure out a way to implement the priority queue for it. Here is the general idea of what I'm trying to do in my .cl file

```
//HOW TO IMPLEMENT THESE??
void extractFromPriorityQueue();
void insertIntoPriorityQueue();
//HOW TO IMPLEMENT THESE??

__kernel void startAStar(//necessary inputs) {
 int id = get_global_id(0);
 int currentNode = extractFromPriorityQueue(priorityQueueArray,id);
  if(currentNode==0){
    return;
  }
 int earliest_edge = vertexArray[currentNode-1];
 int next_vertex_edge = vertexArray[currentNode];
 for(int i=earliest_edge;i<next_vertex_edge;i++){
    int child = edgeArray[i];
    float weight = weightArray[i];
    gCostArray[child-1] = gCostArray[currentNode] + weight;
    hCostArray[child-1] = computeHeuristic(currentNode,child,coordinateArray);
    fCostArray[child-1] = gCostArray[child-1] + hCostArray[child-1];
    insertIntoPriorityQueue(priorityQueueArray,child);
 }
}
```

Also, does the priority queue have to be synchronized in this case?

Answer (score 0):

Below are links to the paper, pptx and source for various lock free GPU data structures including a skip list and priority queue. However the source code is CUDA. The CUDA code  is close enough to OpenCL that you can get the gist of how to implement this in OpenCL.

The priority queue is synchronized using atomic operations.   Queue nodes  are allocated on  the host and passed in as a global array of nodes to the functions. A new node is obtained by using an atomic increment of the array counter.

Nodes are inserted into the queue using atomic compare and swap (exchange) calls.  The paper and ppx
explain the workings  and concurrency issues.

http://www.cse.iitk.ac.in/users/mainakc/projects.html

See the entry in the above page

Parallel programming/Run-time supports
[ICPADS 2012][PDF][Source code][Talk slides (PPTX)]
Prabhakar Misra and Mainak Chaudhuri. Performance Evaluation of Concurrent Lock-free Data Structures on GPUs. In Proceedings of the 18th IEEE International Conference on Parallel and Distributed Systems, pages 53-60, December 2012.

The source code link is  http://www.cse.iitk.ac.in/users/mainakc/lockfree.html

Answer (score 0):

There is another way, if atomic operations are not supported.
You can use the idea to parallelize the Dijkstra's Shortest Path Algorithm from Harish and Narayanan's paper [Accelerating large graph algorithms on the GPU using CUDA](https://www.google.com.br/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CDAQFjAA&url=http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.102.4206&rep=rep1&type=pdf&ei=CIzJUoKeIYbNkAeo4oHACg&usg=AFQjCNFTkNIeffqZG7nVUzLOkEbZ6b3kUA&sig2=3fIgMDIGYTOu7W9kYYp78Q&bvm=bv.58187178,d.eW0).

They suggest to duplicate the arrays for synchronization with the idea of Mask, Cost and Update arrays.

Mask is an unique Boolean array to represent the queue with this size. If an element **i** in this array is true, the element **i** is in the queue.

There are two kernels that guarantees the synchronization:

- The first kernel only reads values from the Cost arrays and only
  writes in Update arrays.
- The second kernel only updates the Cost
  values if they differ from Update. In that case, the upgraded element
  will be set true.

The idea works and there is an implementation made for a Case Study in the OpenCL Programming Guide's book: https://code.google.com/p/opencl-book-samples/source/browse/trunk/src/Chapter_16#Chapter_16%2FDijkstra .